# centering a group inside another group

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have the code below that displays information about a computer.

I am having trouble getting the s:VGroup to appear in the center of s:Group.  It's always slightly off-center...more to the left and the right.

Is there any way to make a group to always be in the center of its container?

I've tried both horizontalAlign="center" and horizontalCenter="center" but neither affect the horizontal positioning of that element.

Thanks!

```
    <s:Group horizontalCenter="center" width="100%" top="10">
    <s:Rect x="0" y="0"  
            radiusX="4" radiusY="4" 
            height="100%" width="90%" left="10">
    </s:Rect>
    <s:VGroup top="20" left="20" bottom="20" right="20">
        <s:Label id="lblCPU"  text="{data.CPU}"/>
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Label id="lblmodel"  text="{data.model}"/>
            <s:Label id="lblmemory"   text="{data.memory}"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:Label id="lblHDD"  text="{data.HDD}"/>
        <s:Label id="lblUSB" text="{data.USB}"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: I've often found the slight offset-ness due to borders. Can you try playing with borders for your Label (inside VGroup) to see if it makes a different. Also, try using flash firebug to see the exact boundary of objects (as against that which is visible to the eye)

Comment: Looks to me like it only _seems_ off center because your bacground Rect isn't centered (you've set it 10px off the left side and none off the right side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<s:Group x="435" y="77" width="200" height="200">
        <s:layout>
            <s:BasicLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:VGroup width="50" height="50" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        </s:VGroup>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: FinFlex's answer will solve your issue. The layout tags can be removed, it won't have a different effect from when you include it.

Comment: Hi FinFlex...Where did you get the X and Y values of 435 and 77?  Thanks!

Comment: I just set those values for demonstration. You can set what ever you like. I tested this with empty project.